# Odd behavior of PFQuery

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am trying to find all posts by the current user. When I add the line `[query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser user]];` the query does not even get executed, since "retrieving posts?" never prints to the console. When I comment out `[query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser user]];` it works just fine. What am I doing wrong?

```
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Post"];

    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
    [query includeKey:@"filter"];

    [query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser user]];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"retrieving posts?");
         ...
    }];
```

Comment: Are Parse logs saying anything? Or can you use breakpoints to see if it gets to the `findObjects` line?

Comment: `[PFUser user]` creates a new user.  You probably want `[PFUser currentUser]`, but that's no excuse for parse not calling the completion block.  That should happen no matter what error your code contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the obj-c but the correct implementation in Swift would be:

`query.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser())`